# Spanish characters (á é í ó ú ñ ) do not display correctly apple mail php mail

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

Hello everyone i need some help.. Currently i am using PHP mail() function . Spanish characters will be in my mail (á é í ó ú ñ) . so normally when i send the mail its no displaying correctly . so i add this line in HTML file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

And this line to php file

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and toal mail function is

```
        $message = "<strong>Nom: </strong>".$_POST["info_Nom"]."<br />";
        $message .= "<strong>Prenom: </strong>".$_POST["prenom"]."<br />";
        $message .= "<strong>Téléphone : </strong>".$_POST["Phone"]."<br />";

        $subject = 'Nouveau message ' . $_POST["info_Nom"];
        $headers = "From: ".$_POST["mail"]."\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

        $send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Then it was working fine in my android gmail app and windows mail. But in apple mail its not displaying correctly [mail app link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204093) . Its displaying like this

```
Nom: test
Prenom: test
TÃ©lÃ©phone : 08019238012
```

Need some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely because of this `$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";`. Use the same encoding.

Comment: but its works fine for windows or android app.. if this is the problem. then what's the solution ? any quotes?

Comment: Again; use the same character encoding for everything, being UTF-8. I.e.: `Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8` including saving the file(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application uses UTF-8 and you want to generate email using ISO-8859-1 you need to actually [convert](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) the text from source to target encoding. Otherwise, it's like renaming `picture.jpg` to `movie.mp4` and expecting to get a video. For example:

```
$source = 'Ñ€';
$target = mb_convert_encoding($source, 'iso-8859-1', 'utf-8');
var_dump(bin2hex($source), bin2hex($target));
```

```
string(10) "c391e282ac"
string(4) "d13f"
```

Please note that `0x3F` in ISO-8859-1 is `?`. That's the replacement character you get when you have a character that does not belong to target encoding, as it's the case with the € symbol.

Now, don't do this. We are almost in 2019. Use UTF-8 everywhere and forget about ancient encodings like ISO-8859-1 or CP850.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments; you need to use the same character encoding for everything, being UTF-8.

I.e.: `Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8` including saving the file(s).